# Executing "java -version" programmatically places the output in StandardError instead of StandardOutput

Tags: c#, java, version

I am facing very strange behavior as I am trying to programmatically detect the java version on my PC. I am using the following C# code:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c java -version");
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
// Get the output into a string
output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   if (output == "")
   output = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
return output;
```

This displays the correct information but the result is found in proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd() instead of proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() as in any other command (i.e. 'java -help').

Even more weird, if I run "java -showversion" which should output both java version and then help information I get the help info in the StandardOutput and the version info is in the StandardError. 
This doesn't make sense to me.

I tested this on 2 Windows 7 x64 machines and 1 XP x32. Same thing everywhere. It's really weird.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @StephenC  excited and sharing i guess

Answer (score 1):

Looks likes this (i.e. version being printed on standard out) is an old issue that sun (oracle) has never fixed in order to avoid breaking legacy systems: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4380614. On linux, **java -version > foo** will create an empty file while **java -version 2> foo** will create a file containing the version.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c java -version");
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
// create event and wait for data receive
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived);
proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();

static void proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;
}

static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;
}
```

Comment: Well my understanding is that the information I am trying to get should be in StandardOutput rather then StandardError. I don't understand why it is in StandardError.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
java -version 2>&1 | more
```

"more" is not required, unless you want to redirect it to file for example.

Works both on *NIX and Win.